Show that given three points are colinear with the circumcircle.
This is a practice math olympic problem from Peru. It is originally in Spanish as following:

I tried to translate as following:
$\triangle ABC$ and $D$ is on $BC$. Let $AD$ intersect the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ in $E$. Let $M$ and $N$ be the midpoint of $AB$ and $CD$ respectively. The segments $MN$ and $AD$ intersect in $F$. Let $G$ be the point of intersection of the circumcircles of $\triangle DNF$ and $\triangle ECF$. Show that $B$, $F$ and $G$ are colinear.
I draw the graph as following:

I can show that $FH$ is parallel to $AB$. I label the midpoint $J$ of $AD$. Then I am stuck. Now I have two ideas only:

I want to show that $B$ has the same power wrt two circles, i.e. I need to show that $BH\cdot BC=BD\cdot BN$.

Or I want to show that $\angle BFD=\angle GND=\angle GCE$.


I do not know how to use the condition of midpoints $M,N$. I need helps.

You're very close! You have made the right observations. Focus on showing 1. $\quad$ Hint: The observation that $FH \parallel AB$ yields 2 sets of similar triangles. What are they?  This allows you to make use of the conditions of midpoints, by comparing side lengths. Hence determine $DH$ in terms of $CB$ and $DN$, and verify 1. holds.

Thanks a lot, Calvin. I get it now.

You're very close, and have made the right observations.
Let $ BC = a, AB = c, CN=ND = x, DH = k$.

OP wants to show that $BH \times BC = BD \times BN$.

This means that  $(a - 2x - k) \times a = (a-x) \times ( a - 2x)$.
Solving for $k$ yields $ k = \frac{ x(a-2x) } {a}$, which we will show.


OP said that $FH \parallel AB$, so this gives us some similar triangles to work with.

First pair: $ DFH \sim DAB$ so $ \frac{k}{a-2x} = \frac{ DH}{DB} = \frac{FH}{AB} = \frac{ FH}{c} $
Second pair: $NFH \sim NMB $ so $\frac{ x+k}{a-x} = \frac{NH}{NB} = \frac{ FH}{MB} = \frac{ FH}{c/2} $.
Thus $ \frac{ k}{a-2x} = \frac{ FH}{c} = \frac{ x+k} { 2(a-x) } $. Solving for $k$ yields $ k = \frac{ x(a-2x) } { a} $ as desired.


It remains to explain why OP's desire of $BH \times BC = BD \times BN$ implies that $BFG$ is collinear

This shows that $B$ is on the radical axis $FG$.



Note

This solution follows from OP's observations, and attempts to push through from there.
I'm sure there's a better explanation. The algebra is just too nice for this to be a coincidence (or for them to guess that this will happen).

